# Can you accept Paypal Payments Without Merchant account and SSL certificated website?

Tags: ssl, paypal

I searched for answers to these questions but could not find the answer. We are a social group (non-profit, non-charitable) that would like to set up registration and payment for events we sponsor via our website. Our website does not have an SSL certificate however, and from what I've been reading, the redirect URL needs to be a HTTPS:// url. Are there other options for websites without SSL certificates?

Also, we have a PayPal account set up for our group to receive monies, do we need to set this up as a business or merchant account to be able to receive payments? If so, which one? I am not sure I understand the differences between the two.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't Meetup or some other quasi-social-meeting site provide all of this already? Perhpas you should use something that's supported, tested and audited already rather than roll your own.

Comment: *"Our website does not have an SSL certificate..."* - you can get a free Class 1 server certificate from [Startcom](http://www.startcom.org/) and [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/). They are trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'https/ssl' you mean whether your site itself needs to support SSL traffic over HTTP (and thus have a valid SSL certificate): no, it doesn't.

You do however need to be able to establish an SSL connection. Specifically, to PayPal's API endpoint.
This means you need to allow outbound SSL traffic via your firewall (if you have any) and your environment needs to support this.

Ensure you have a valid copy of the root certs (I usually suggesthttp://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) to valid the SSL certificates against.